# Adding a column to a view with result

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have created a view in SQL-SERVER and I would also like to be able to add a column to the returned result of this view.

Here is my code:

```
 ALTER VIEW [eConnect].[GetStudentTeachers]
AS
    select 
        srmitv.StudentId as StudentId, 
        srmitv.TeacherAlias as Alias, 
        srmitv.TeacherAvatarFileName as AvatarFileName, 
        srmitv.TeacherMessageUserId as MessageUserId, 
        srmitv.TeacherUserName as UserName,
        sp.Sex as Gender,
    from 
        StudentRegularModuleInstanceTeachersView srmitv 
        inner join Sync_Persons sp on srmitv.TeacherId = sp.TeacherID and sp.Deletion_Date is null

    union 
    select 
        somirtv.StudentId as StudentId, 
        somirtv.TeacherAlias as Alias, 
        somirtv.TeacherAvatarFileName as AvatarFileName, 
        somirtv.TeacherMessageUserId as MessageUserId, 
        somirtv.TeacherUserName as UserName,
        sp.Sex as Gender
    from 
        dbo.StudentOlcModuleInstanceRelatedTeachersView somirtv
        inner join Sync_Persons sp on somirtv.TeacherId = sp.TeacherID and sp.Deletion_Date is null
GO
```

Now I would like to add another column here RoleId that always has the value 1.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to the select:          `1 as RoleId`

```
ALTER VIEW [eConnect].[GetStudentTeachers]
AS
    select 
        srmitv.StudentId as StudentId, 
        srmitv.TeacherAlias as Alias, 
        srmitv.TeacherAvatarFileName as AvatarFileName, 
        srmitv.TeacherMessageUserId as MessageUserId, 
        srmitv.TeacherUserName as UserName,
        sp.Sex as Gender,
        1 as RoleId 

    from 
        StudentRegularModuleInstanceTeachersView srmitv 
        inner join Sync_Persons sp on srmitv.TeacherId = sp.TeacherID and sp.Deletion_Date is null

    union 
    select 
        somirtv.StudentId as StudentId, 
        somirtv.TeacherAlias as Alias, 
        somirtv.TeacherAvatarFileName as AvatarFileName, 
        somirtv.TeacherMessageUserId as MessageUserId, 
        somirtv.TeacherUserName as UserName,
        sp.Sex as Gender,
        1 as RoleId 
    from 
        dbo.StudentOlcModuleInstanceRelatedTeachersView somirtv
        inner join Sync_Persons sp on somirtv.TeacherId = sp.TeacherID and sp.Deletion_Date is null
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
SELECT 1 AS RoleID, * FROM [eConnect].[GetStudentTeachers]
```